# Is it not thread safe to test a flag in an if condition in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote the following code for trap ctrl-c. I simply use the "flag" to break the while true loop. But someone suggested me to do it in
another way.

```c#
class Program {

    private object mutex = new object();
    private bool flag = false;

    protected void CtrlCHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
       lock(mutex)
       {
           flag = true;
       }
    }
    public Program()
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(CtrlCHandler);
        Console.WriteLine("Program Started!\n");
        while (true){
            if (flag) break;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
     }

     public static void Main()
     {
        new Program();
     }
 }
```

Second Method. He added a private method to the while true loop instead. why is this method preferred for thread-safe? I am a noob in multi-threading. Please give some advice.

```c#
class Program {

    private object mutex = new object();
    private bool flag = false;

    protected void CtrlCHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
       lock(mutex)
       {
           flag = true;
       }
    }
    private bool changeFlag(){
       bool returnValue = false;
       lock(mutex)
       {
           returnValue = flag;
       }
       return returnValue;
    }
    public Program()
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(CtrlCHandler);
        Console.WriteLine("Program Started!\n");
        while (true){
            if (changeFlag()) break;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
     }

     public static void Main()
     {
        new Program();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Consider how you (the compiler) might optimize the first case. You know `Thread.Sleep(1);` can't modify `flag`. So you can optimize out the repeated checks of `flag`. And the only thing that would break is some case where `flag` is used in this particular way. Which makes more sense -- 1) Disable this very valuable optimization in the thousands of cases where it helps just in case it's being used to signal between threads. or 2) Require people who use variables to signal between threads to clearly indicate that in their code and only disable the optimization where necessary.

Comment: The real problem here is simply that you're doing a busy wait until a boolean flips. Don't do that.  Have the thread actually not be running until you're ready for it to run.

Comment: `ManualResetEventSlim.Set()`, `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait()`/`.IsSet()`. Alternatively, use a `Task` with a `CancellationToken` and `.IsCancellationRequested` if you must keep busy. Any code that contains `Thread.Sleep(1)` anywhere is almost certainly wrong, as that's the worst kind of busy waiting loop. Any code where you're not sure if the threading is OK is likewise almost certainly wrong -- and even when it isn't, the fact that you're not sure is a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

The flag value can be cached per thread and changes to it in other threads effectively ignored.  You need to tell the framework that you want to see those changes.  in your first example you can do that by including a lock in your code that checks `flag`.  For example:

```
    while (true){
        lock(mutex) {
            if (flag) break;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```